# How best to change the height of View dynamically?

Tags: android, height

I know two options, but do not know which one is better, but it is better not to use coca. For me, the latter is preferable. I would like to hear the views of professionals and comments. The options are:

```
1 ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,100);
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

`2 view.getLayoutParams().height = 100;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter one is better because it doesn't create a new object and avoid a small garbage.But you should always  check if the returned `LayoutParams` is null although it is non-null once added to the view tree.

So another approach:

```
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
        if(lp != null) {
            lp.height = 100;
        } else {
            //you should use a subclass of ViewGroup.LayoutParams in your product 
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        }
```

Comment: Accurate to change the width of View in this way?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
boolean isHeightChanged;
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
      if(!isHeightChanged){
          isHeightChanged=true;
          view.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
      }
   }
});
```